# Counting the number of one in a list

Tags: python-3.x, arraylist, counter

I already know the number of columns which is 3. The program asks the user to enter the number of rows
After that, the program tries to see for each row if the number of one entered by the user for each line is greater or equal to 2  and do the sum of the number of rows that the one is greater or equal to one
like if we have entered 3 like a number of rows. we have to enter the value that is either 0 or one for each row (each row has three-element) let's join these values
1 0 1
1 1 1
0 1 0
the program will print 2(Because the row 1 and row 2 have the number of one greater than one each)
Here is the code that I wrote. But I'm unable to count the number of one for each row

```
tab=[]
ligne=int(input('Enter rows : '))
column=1
for i in range(ligne):
    a=[]
    for k in range(column):
        new=(input())
        so=new.split()
        a.append(new)
        print()
    tab.append(a)

for i in range(ligne):
   for k in range(column):
         for c in range(len(so)):
            so[i][k] = int(so[i][k])
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
count = 0
for row in matrix:
    if row.count(1) > 1:
        count += 1
```

Input:

```py
# I hardcoded the matrix for demo.
matrix = [
    [1, 0, 1],
    [1, 1, 1],
    [0, 1, 0],
]
```

Output:

```py
>>> print(count)
>>> 2
```